# Dynamic modify or generate code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, dynamic, code-generation

I am doing multi sorting on some table data. I want to dynamically modify the line of code in my AngularJS site that specifies the priority order of the sorting. (I'm just modifying the structure of the array, since AngularJS watched the bound-data for changes and reflects them in the HTML display dynamically.)

For multi sort I am using [thenBy.js](https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js/tree/master). Essentially you create a variable beginning with *firstBy( comparativeFunction)* and then you can append on as many *thenBy(comparativeFunction)* as you like.

I am dynamically adding and removing sort-comparators as necessary. Here's where I start with this simple two-level multi-sort:

```
// I want to modify and append to this line
var s = firstBy( (a, b) => a["Status"].localeCompare(b["Status"]) )
  .thenBy( (a, b) => parseFloat(a["#"]) - parseFloat(b["#"]) );
```

It would initially sort the rows based on the data in the "Status" properties, then sub-sort on the "#" which is the ID-number.

What I want to know is how to dynamically add more code the line above. For example, say I wanted to add a third-level sort, like on "Uniquie ID". Hard coding the line I could do it like this:

```
var s = firstBy( (a, b) => a["Status"].localeCompare(b["Status"]) )
  .thenBy( (a, b) => parseFloat(a["#"]) - parseFloat(b["#"]) )
  .thenBy( (a, b) => parseFloat(a["Unique ID"]) - parseFloat(b["Unique ID"]) );
```

I am just not sure how to programmically append more 'thenBy()' methods to that one line. Should I generate a string and run it through ***eval()***? Is there a better (safer) way?

Here is the program currently:

```
self.dataSource = [
    {"#": "1", "Unique ID": "100130", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "2", "Unique ID": "100131", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "3", "Unique ID": "100132", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 3", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "4", "Unique ID": "100133", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 4", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "5", "Unique ID": "100134", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 5", "Status": "Checked Out"},
    {"#": "6", "Unique ID": "100135", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 6", "Status": "Checked Out"},
    {"#": "7", "Unique ID": "100136", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 7", "Status": "Checked Out"},
    {"#": "8", "Unique ID": "100137", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 8", "Status": "Checked Out"},
    {"#": "9", "Unique ID": "100138", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "10", "Unique ID": "100139", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "11", "Unique ID": "100140", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "12", "Unique ID": "100141", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 3", "Status": "Lost"},
    {"#": "13", "Unique ID": "100142", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 4", "Status": "Lost"},
    {"#": "14", "Unique ID": "100143", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 3 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "15", "Unique ID": "100144", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 3 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "16", "Unique ID": "100145", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Checked Out"},
    {"#": "17", "Unique ID": "100146", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "18", "Unique ID": "100147", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 3", "Status": "Available"},
    {"#": "19", "Unique ID": "100148", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 4", "Status": "Checked Out"},
    {"#": "20", "Unique ID": "100149", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 5 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"}       
];

var self = this;

self.multiSortDict = {};

self.addSort = function(sortName, sortComparatorFunction)
{
    self.multiSortDict[sortName] = sortComparatorFunction;
}

// Example code to add a bunch of sorting methods
self.addSort("Status",(a, b) => a["Status"].localeCompare(b["Status"]));
self.addSort("#", (a, b) => parseFloat(a["#"]) - parseFloat(b["#"]));
self.addSort("Name",(a, b) => a["Name"].localeCompare(b["Name"]));
self.addSort("Unique ID", (a, b) => parseFloat(a["Unique ID"]) - parseFloat(b["Unique ID"]));
self.addSort("Position",(a, b) => a["Position"].localeCompare(b["Position"]));


self.rebuildMultiSort = function (multiSortDict) {
    var sortList = Object.values(multiSortDict);

    var sortMethod = firstBy( sortList[0] ); // Grab the first entry to set the 'firstBy()' method

    for (var i = 1; i < sortList.length; i++) { // Starting at second position
        // I want to dynamically modify this line, being able to append as many 'thenBy()' statements as necessary
        // remove the semicolon from the previous sortMethod assignment
        // append the new 'thenBy()' to assignment
        sortMethod +=
            .thenBy(value);
    }
    return sortMethod;
}
```

Using the above example, ideally I would get a code-line that is something like this:

```
var s = firstBy( (a, b) => a["Status"].localeCompare(b["Status"]) )
  .thenBy( (a, b) => parseFloat(a["#"]) - parseFloat(b["#"]) )
  .thenBy( "Name",(a, b) => a["Name"].localeCompare(b["Name"]) )
  .thenBy( (a, b) => parseFloat(a["Unique ID"]) - parseFloat(b["Unique ID"]) )
  .thenBy( "Position",(a, b) => a["Position"].localeCompare(b["Position"]) )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, there is a better way of doing things than employing `evil`.

I would suggest having a lookup of comparison functions, something like

```
const ordersLookup = {
  Status: (a, b) => a["Status"].localeCompare(b["Status"]),
  "#": (a, b) => parseFloat(a["#"]) - parseFloat(b["#"]),
  Name: (a, b) => a["Name"].localeCompare(b["Name"]),
  // ...
}
```

Then when you decide what you want to sort on:

```
let order = ["Name", "Status"];
```

and pick the appropriate entry from the lookup, and reduce the chain:

```
let s = order.reduce((a, e) => a.thenBy(ordersLookup[e]), firstBy(() => 0));
```

or

```
let orderFunctions = order.map(e => ordersLookup[e]);
let [firstInOrder, *restInOrder] = orderFunctions;
let s = restInOrder.reduce((a, e) => a.thenBy(e), firstBy(firstInOrder));
```

(The end result should be the same, performance and readability differ a bit).

No code generation required.

Also, note that thenBy.js knows how to handle sorting by properties, so you don't need to write most of those functions yourself. `firstBy("Name").thenBy("#")` should work out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. This example worked after I tinkered with it. This seems to be doing the job I was looking for!